# How to skip a tag and move to next one - web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the Tesco website to get the name and price of products. Below is my code. Some products do not have a price as they are sold out and Python gives me an error because there is nothing to scrape. I want it to be able to skip that tile and move on to the next one if a price is not available.

Anyone know how I can do this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#URL to be scraped
url_to_scrape = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all?page=1&count=48'
#Load html's plain data into a variable
plain_html_text = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
#parse the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.text, "lxml")

#Get the name of the class
for name_of in soup.find_all('div',class_='product-tile-wrapper'):
    name =name_of.h3.a.text
    print(name)
    price = name_of.find('div', class_='price-details--wrapper')
    pricen =price.find('span', class_='value').text
    print(pricen)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` - `except` block:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#URL to be scraped
url_to_scrape = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all?page=1&count=48'
#Load html's plain data into a variable
plain_html_text = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
#parse the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.text, "lxml")

#Get the name of the class
for name_of in soup.find_all('div',class_='product-tile-wrapper'):
    try:
        name =name_of.h3.a.text
        print(name)
        price = name_of.find('div', class_='price-details--wrapper')
        pricen =price.find('span', class_='value').text
        print(pricen)
    except:
        pass
```

You could also make it more interactive by:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#URL to be scraped
url_to_scrape = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all?page=1&count=48'
#Load html's plain data into a variable
plain_html_text = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
#parse the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_html_text.text, "lxml")

#Get the name of the class
for name_of in soup.find_all('div',class_='product-tile-wrapper'):
    name =name_of.h3.a.text
    print(name)
    try:
        price = name_of.find('div', class_='price-details--wrapper')
        pricen =price.find('span', class_='value').text
        print(pricen)
    except:
        print('Sold Out')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you know how i can change the code so its works through a number of links and get the data. So this link is for fresh food, i want to get data for frozen food, drink etc.

Comment: That can be asked as another question in SO. feel free to do so because it has nothing to do with this question

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua! Very helpful